# PySpark - how to take schema from one dataframe and apply it to another?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have `DF1` with correct Schema (column names and data types).

How to apply schema from DF1 to DF2? (even if DF2 already has one)

I tried `df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2.rdd, df1.schema)` and that changes the schema but might give error for Data Types as:

`TypeError: field ID: LongType can not accept object 8377813.0 in type <class 'float'>`

Is it better to cast? If so - how to do for every column?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the nature of the schemas? What conversions do you need exactly? Can you provide an example dataset?

Comment: You should do this when you create the `df2` but you are doing alter I think.

Comment: I need to union 2 dataframes. What is the way to do that if they are different schema?